# TypeError when debugging scikit-learn GridSearchCV in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn

I am getting the following error when I try to debug my python code in visual studio. Surprisingly, the code works fine when I run the code without debugging. Any clues?

TypeError: unbound method new_CreateProcess() must be called with _winapi instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
PS C:\GitHub\Project>

Here is the piece of code causing the error. It is a standard grid-search initialization in scikit-learn. I am not sure what I am missing. I am using Python 2.7.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=p_grid, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=4, cv=inner_cv, refit=True, return_train_score=True)
clf.fit(x, y)
```

The clf.fit() line is where the error happens. Here is the complete traceback for the above code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.read_csv([some file])
x = df.iloc[:,3:-1]
y = df.loc[:, 'Label']
colNames = x.columns

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
for i in range(2,x.shape[1]):
   columnName = x.columns[i]
   x[columnName] = scaler.fit_transform(x[columnName].values.reshape(-1,1))

p_grid = {'n_estimators' : list(range(10,101,10)),
         'max_features' : list(range(6,30,5))}
model = RandomForestClassifier()

numTrials = 30

non_nested_scores = np.zeros(numTrials)
nested_scores = []
scores = {'auc': 'roc_auc', 'f1': 'f1', 'precision':'precision', 'recall':'recall', 'accuracy':'accuracy'}
resultsLog = pd.DataFrame(columns=['trial','auc','f1','precision','recall','accuracy'])
for i in range(numTrials):

    n = 5
    inner_cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
    outer_cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=i)

    # Non_nested parameter search and scoring
    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=p_grid, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=-1, cv=inner_cv, refit=True, return_train_score=True)
    clf = clf.fit(x,y)
    non_nested_scores[i] = clf.best_score_

    # Nested CV with parameter optimization
    nested_score = cross_validate(clf,
                                   X=x,
                                   y=y,
                                   scoring=scores,
                                   cv=outer_cv,
                                   n_jobs=-1)
m1 = np.mean(nested_score['test_auc'])
m2 = np.mean(nested_score['test_f1'])
m3 = np.mean(nested_score['test_precision'])
m4 = np.mean(nested_score['test_recall'])
m5 = np.mean(nested_score['test_accuracy'])
newRow = pd.DataFrame({'trial':[i], 'auc':[m1], 'f1':[m2], 'precision':[m3], 'recall':[m4], 'accuracy':[m5]})
resultsLog = pd.concat([resultsLog, newRow], ignore_index=True)
nested_scores.append(nested_score)
```

Comment: Can you include the complete traceback? Otherwise it's not obvious where the exception is coming from.

Comment: @BrettCannon Thanks for looking into this. I have added the complete traceback as you suggested. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: unfortunately it looks like you pasted the code and not the traceback. What I'm after is everything to do with the `TypeError` message.

Comment: This is the error message I am getting: Exception has occurred: TypeError
unbound method new_CreateProcess() must be called with _winapi instance as first argument (got str instance instead) -- Does this answer your question? If not, please let me know how can I provide more info. Thank you so much! @BrettCannon

Comment: If that's the entire error message that's not much to go on as it doesn't say where `new_CreateProcess()` is being called. This means who knows who is printing that error message and thus what is unhappy. At this point I would file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd.